# How to set time stamp in to the email address

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

How can I easy set time stamp in to the email ? Format for example xxxddd23031990@gmy.com

```
    private static class CustomerProperties
    {
     public static readonly string EmailFieldName = "xxxddd@gmy.com";
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Something like `new Date(2016, 11, 16).ToString("yyyddd")`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean:)

Comment: Google knows... you should ask. Do some research on your own before asking questions here. Questions should show some effort on your part. Please post the code you have tried and the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work, using today's date (DateTime.Now) as an example. Note that production code would require you to check for potential exception conditions, e.g. the non-presence of the @ symbol in the email address.

```
var dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
var emailAddress = CustomerProperties.EmailFieldName;
var timeStampedEmailAddress = emailAddress.Insert(emailAddress.IndexOf("@"), dateString);
```